# How to center main part of navbar?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a navbar which has 4 anchor tag buttons in the center (home, about, services, contact). I dont know how to center it on the navbar. I have another anchor tag on the far left of the navbar (a phone number link). It appears that the part I want to center is centered between the boundary of that far left link and the far right of the page.

I cant figure out how to center these 4 tags on the grid.

Hope that makes sense, im not too good with the jargon.

```
                                <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"  style="color:grey; display:inline-block">1-530-680- 
                                        8255</a>

                                         <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"><i class="fas fa-phone" style="display:inline-block"> 
                                          </i>1-530-680-8255</a>




                        </div>
                        <nav class="navigation nav-block secondary-navigation nav-right">
                            <ul>
                                <!-- Dropdown Cart Overview
                                <li>
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="nav-icon cart button no-page-fade"><span class="cart-indication"><span class="icon-shopping-cart"></span> <span class="badge">3</span></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-list custom-content cart-overview">
                                            <li class="cart-item">
                                                <a href="single-product.html" class="product-thumbnail">
                                                    <img src="images/design-agency/portfolio/grid/no-margins/project-6-square.jpg" alt="" />
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="product-details">
                                                    <a href="single-product.html" class="product-title">
                                                        Cotton Jump Suit
                                                    </a>
                                                    <span class="product-quantity">2 x</span>
                                                    <span class="product-price"><span class="currency">$</span>15.00</span>
                                                    <a href="#" class="product-remove icon-cancel"></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="cart-item">
                                                <a href="single-product.html" class="product-thumbnail">
                                                    <img src="images/design-agency/portfolio/grid/no-margins/project-7-square.jpg" alt="" />
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="product-details">
                                                    <a href="single-product.html" class="product-title">
                                                        Cotton Jump Suit
                                                    </a>
                                                    <span class="product-quantity">2 x</span>
                                                    <span class="product-price"><span class="currency">$</span>15.00</span>
                                                    <a href="#" class="product-remove icon-cancel"></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="cart-item">
                                                <a href="single-product.html" class="product-thumbnail">
                                                    <img src="images/design-agency/portfolio/grid/no-margins/project-8-square.jpg" alt="" />
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="product-details">
                                                    <a href="single-product.html" class="product-title">
                                                        Cotton Jump Suit
                                                    </a>
                                                    <span class="product-quantity">2 x</span>
                                                    <span class="product-price"><span class="currency">$</span>15.00</span>
                                                    <a href="#" class="product-remove icon-cancel"></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="cart-subtotal">
                                                Sub Total
                                                <span class="amount"><span class="currency">$</span>15.00</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="cart-actions">
                                                <a href="cart.html" class="view-cart">View Cart</a>
                                                <a href="checkout.html" class="checkout button small"><span class="icon-check"></span> Checkout</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li> -->
                                <!-- Dropdown Search Module
                                <li>
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="nav-icon search button no-page-fade"><span class="icon-magnifying-glass"></span></a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-list custom-content cart-overview">
                                            <div class="search-form-container site-search">
                                                <form action="#" method="get" novalidate>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="column width-12">
                                                            <div class="field-wrapper">
                                                                <input type="text" name="search" class="form-search form-element no-margin-bottom" placeholder="type &amp; hit enter...">
                                                                <span class="border"></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                                <div class="form-response"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li> -->

                                <li>
                                        <div class="v-align-middle" style="margin-left: 60px;">
                                            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="aux-navigation hide">
                                        <!-- Aux Navigation -->
                                        <a href="#" class="navigation-show side-nav-show nav-icon">
                                            <span class="icon-menu"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        <nav class="navigation nav-block primary-navigation nav-center">


                            <ul>
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home <i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">About <i class="fas fa-at"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Services <i class="fas fa-wrench"></i> </a></li>
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Contact <i class="fas fa-phone"></i> </a></li>


                            </ul>

                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: What have you tried? You should try and provide a JS fiddle of the scenario so we can take a look at a working example.

Comment: Please add the relevant CSS

Comment: So im working from a template, and Im not entirely sure where the relevant css is. Thats sort of my problem. I dont even now where to look to alter things in css. How do i include a fiddle? I have an account and the html and css loaded in a fiddle page.just dont know how to show people here

Answer (score 0):

You can use floats to position elements side by side on the page and then play with the widths and padding to arrange them how you like. If you are unsure how to use CSS I suggest following some online tutorials.

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav ul li span {
  font-size: 0.7em;
}

nav ul li i {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.left {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">



<nav>
  <div class="left">
    <p>000 000 0000</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i><br><span>Contact</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-wrench"></i><br><span>Services</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-at"></i><br><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><br><span>Home</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: ok i have it centered the way i want. Problem now is that the box its contained in is vertically way too large. how do i shrink this down to the original size?

I took this css:

Comment: @RobbieNichols Could be several reasons of this. If you right click in the browser and select 'inspect' a panel will pop up that allows you to inspect the elements on the page. You will be able to see the height of elements and if there is any padding on them. It could be as simple as setting the height of Nav but without looking its hard to say. the "margin: 200px;" is probably a problem too, as it will be setting the margin on all sides including the top and bottom. U could use 'margin: 20px 400px;' or even better look into setting the width of the ul and then "li {margin: 20px auto;}"

Comment: i changed the ul width and got it perfectly centered. But now my hamburger dropdown menu is gone when i go to mobile size.....UGH!

Comment: @RobbieNichols welcome to Web development. there is always a problem to fix. the  hamburger menu could be a z-index problem. It's a bit out of the scope of your original question though.

Answer (score 0):

there is alot of existing css that came with this template. For me to run your css and html, it would change too many properties to the point where its unrecognizable. Despite that this is a perfect answer. HOWEVER: I took your css:

```
nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;

}
```

and i changed it to these values:

```
nav ul {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
width: 1100px;
margin: 200px;
padding: 200px;
 }
```

Its centered. But now the container is vertically huge. Need it the original height

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmnu4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets start over. I just want to center these 4 anchor tag li's inside of this ul.

Is there someway I can wrap these four into one container, and then move them to the left with css? I just want those 4 items to appear centered in that ul.

[Heres a picture of what im talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yNXg.png)

Below is my total header in html. Theres a lot of CSS so i dont know what to link people to but ill put what i have been playing with below.

```
<!-- Header -->
        <header class="header header-fixed header-fixed-on-mobile header-transparent" data-bkg-threshold="100">
            <div class="header-inner">
                <div class="row nav-bar">
                    <div class="column width-12 nav-bar-inner">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <div>


                                <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"  style="color:grey; display:inline-block">1-530-680- 
                                        8255</a>

                                         <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"><i class="fas fa-phone" style="display:inline-block"> 
                                          </i>1-530-680-8255</a>



                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <nav class="navigation nav-block secondary-navigation nav-right">
                            <ul>



                                    <li class="aux-navigation hide">
                                        <!-- Aux Navigation -->
                                        <a href="#" class="navigation-show side-nav-show nav-icon">
                                            <span class="icon-menu"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        <nav class="navigation nav-block primary-navigation nav-center">
                            <ul>

                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home <i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">About <i class="fas fa-at"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Services <i class="fas fa-wrench"></i> </a></li>
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Contact <i class="fas fa-phone"></i> </a></li>


                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Header End -->
```

---CSS---

```
nav ul li  {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
width: 100px;
margin: 00px;
padding: 0px;
 }
```